# Shifting elements in an array a particular way

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

The goal of this method is that I have a 2D array filled with Bubble objects and I am trying to shift everything in the array that does not have a color value of 0 down and leave the color 0 at the top of the column.
At the moment it turns every spot into a bubble with a value of 0.  I'm thinking its a small logic error that im missing but I have been trying for 3 days now and cant see my issue.  *Clarification: myBoard is initialized as new Bubble [15][15]; and the Bubble Constructor is (int color, int row, int col)

```
public void shiftBoardDown() {

    int currentC = 0;

    while(currentC < 15){
        Bubble [] temp = new Bubble [15];
        int hits = 14;

        for(int i = 14; i <= 0; i--){
            if(this.myBoard[i][currentC].getColor() != 0){
                temp[hits] = new Bubble(this.myBoard[i][currentC].getColor(), hits, currentC);
                hits--;
            }
        }

        while(hits >= 0){
            temp[hits] = new Bubble(0, hits, currentC);
            hits--;
        }
        for(int r = 0; r < 15; r++){
            this.myBoard[r][currentC] = temp[r];
        }
        currentC++;
    }

}
```

Comment: What language is this? Tag the question appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing

```
if(this.myBoard[i][currentC].getColor() != 0)
```

Never gets triggered and the following loop is entered with `hits==14`.

```
while(hits >= 0){
    temp[hits] = new Bubble(0, hits, currentC);
    hits--;
}
```

In that case `hits` runs from 14 to 0 inclusive setting the corresponding entry in temp to a color 0 `Bubble`.

Set a break point on `hits--' in the first loop to confirm if it ever gets triggered.

I can't tell because I can how the state of `this.myBoard[i]` entering the function.

Comment: Thanks that was right, my issue was in the first for loop i accidentally did < instead of >